# what does the colon mean in the Twitter API Resource URL format?

Tags: api, url, twitter

The Twitter API for retweeting shows as the Resource URL the following:

http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/retweet/:id.format

and it says then that "id" is a required parameter.

So based on this I thought that the following AIFNetworking call would work. Where I set:
postPath:@"1.1/statuses/retweet.json"

and parameters:
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:@{@"id": tweetID}];

And the entire call looks like:

```
- (void)postARetweet:(NSString*)tweetID success:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id response))success failure:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error))failure {

NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:@{@"id": tweetID}];
self postPath:@"1.1/statuses/retweet.json" parameters:params success:success failure:failure];}
```

But I got a 404 error telling me the page didn't exist. After much trial and error, i forced the postPath to be

```
postpath:@"1.1/statuses/retweet/@"some_tweet_number".json"
```

and that worked.

SO I do not understand why the "params" entry for "id" key did not get appended to the original postpath as it is supposed to do . My only thought is that perhaps the postpath has to include the "id" and in addition the same "id" as a parameter.

So what does the :id mean in the Resource URL?? 
Why would the API required the "id" of the tweet to be part of the URL path and in addition passed as a parameter? Seems redundant.

thanks

-Malena

Answer (score 5):

Let's say that you want to retweet a tweet with the ID of `123456`.  That number is the `:id`.

Now, let's say that you want the response to be in XML.  That's the `format`.

So you can have

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/retweet/123456.xml
```

or

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/retweet/123456.json
```

Do note that the API has changed to version 1.1.  You should carefully read the documentation at  https://api.twitter.com/1.1/

For Retweet documentation, see https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/post/statuses/retweet/%3Aid

Comment: If you have found my answer useful, please upvote or accept it. Thanks :-)